# Unit Testcase - Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View

Tags: unit-testing, swiftui

I have tried various ways to fix the warning, but the warning keeps coming.
I tried creating @stateObject and accessing it from separate state as well, the warning is still there. I have moved it to .onAppear, even it does not change anything. Can anyone help, what is the actual problem here, how do I resolve it.

"Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update."

Sample code.

```
 Struct Screens: View {
    @State private var showScreen = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            if showScreenButton {
                showScreen = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showScreen) { //Warning here
            showScreen = false
        } content: {
            displayScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Test case - In real time, it's working well without warnings.

```
    func test_Screen() throws {
        let betaObject = BetaView().environmentObject(betaContent).environmentObject(betaVM)
        let baseView = try betaObject.inspect() 

        let screenView = try baseView.find(Screens.self) //Whenever this line triggers
        XCTAssertNotNil(screenView, "screen View")
    }
```

Comment: You have to add : View to the screens declararion

Comment: Sorry, it was missed while editing the code to share it here.